# MVC File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an excel file and then grab the email's out of them. Issue is I can't upload the file. Request.Files is always empty.

Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="txtUploadFile" class="makethispretty" />
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import()
    {

        ArrayList newUsers = new ArrayList();
        newUsers.Add("hello");
        // Filter Regex
        string regex = "^[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*@google.edu$";
        Regex r = new Regex(regex);
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/excel/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Let's see how you're creating the form in the view, I bet you're not setting it to be multipart.

Comment: And you will find easier to just use `public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing something like this to make it multipart:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName",
        FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```